# Stop insects from flying into my cooldrink?

Tags: bugs

Often when I go camping, insects like flies fly into my glass. Are there any good ways to stop this?

Also, recently someone told me that I could put a pencil on the glass to stop insects. Does it really work?

Comment: You could regard the insects as protein that you did not have to pack in.  I've never heard of the pencil trick, but a pencil would be good to fish the insects out.   I rarely use a glass or cup, but only plastic bottles, which, of course have caps.

Comment: Cover your glass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never heard of the pencil trick and I'd be wary. But using a cup with a lid is probably the most obvious choice.

Comment: Why in the world did this get down voted? It's the only and best answer.